# "The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned, but the return type, 'FutureOr<List<Article>>', is a potentially non-nullable type."

Tags: flutter, api, rest, dart, flutter-dependencies

I was trying to make a News App with [newsapi.org](https://newsapi.org/), but got this error:

```
The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned, 
but the return type, 'FutureOr<List<Article>>', is a potentially non-nullable type.
Try adding either a return or a throw statement at the end.
```

Error from:

```dart
getArticle()
```

I've read a lot of ppl with the same problem and most of them told me to add `return` or a `throw`, which I already did but the error still appears.

So here's my code:

```dart
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart';
import 'package:medreminder/NewsArticle/models/article_models.dart';

class ApiService {
  final endPointUrl = 
      "https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&apiKey=cacee27fff544eb39d5fb29b28ca3788"; 

  Future<List<Article>> getArticle() async {
    Response res = await get(Uri.parse(endPointUrl));

    if(res.statusCode == 200) {
      Map<String, dynamic> json = jsonDecode(res.body);
      List<dynamic> body = json['articles'];
      List<Article> articles = 
          body.map((dynamic item) => Article.fromJson(item)).toList();
    } else {
      throw("Cant get the News");
    }
  }
}
```

Let me know if you guys need to see my other code if necessary. Thank you guys

Comment: Your `getArticle` function neglects to do `return articles;` for the `res.statusCode == 200` case.

Comment: In fact, you can just return the last expression of that branch.  You aren't using articles elsewhere.

Comment: im confused since im new in flutter, so what should i add in the code to make the error's gone?

Comment: @RandalSchwartz _"you can just return the last expression of that branch."_ You actually can't, since the list of `articles` is defined _within_ the `if` statement.

Comment: @NyK See me edits

Comment: @MendelG.  Yes, return it from inside the if.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error states:

> Try adding either a return or a throw statement at the end.

You need to `return` something. In your case it's a `List<Article>`.

> I've read a lot of ppl with the same problem, most of them told to add return or a throw, which I already did but the error still appearing.

This is probably because you are adding the return statement *within* your `if`/`else` statement, so if your condition isn't met, then you still might not return anything.

To avoid the error, your code should look like this (null safe):

```dart
 Future<List<Article>?> getArticle() async{
    Response res = await get(Uri.parse(endPointUrl));

    if(res.statusCode==200){
      Map<String, dynamic> json = jsonDecode(res.body);

      List<dynamic> body = json['articles'];

      List<Article> articles = body.map((dynamic item) => Article.fromJson(item)).toList();
      return articles;
    }else{

      return null;
    }

  }
```

Now, this function is nullable - which means that if the response is 200, it will return the `articles`. Otherwise, it will return `null`

Comment: "Otherwise, it will return `null`" That's not possible since response codes that aren't 200 will throw.  Either return a `Future` with a non-nullable type or replace the `throw` failure.